# Java 11 and javax.annotation: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, java-11, rcp

our RCP OSGi Application does not run anymore after upgrading to Java 11. This is because Java 11 removed javax.annotation and this leads to the following Exception while running our application:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at *.application.Application.start(Application.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.8.200.v20220512-1957
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 25 more
```

The Eclipse Plugin for Dependency Injection "org.eclipse.e4.core.di" cannot find the javax.annotation package at runtime right after starting the application. The Application runs as mentioned in an OSGi Container. There are no unresolved requirements or something similar at Compile time, furthermore javax.annotation is present in the Build and in the target platform. See the Manifest of the org.eclipse.e4.core.di Bundle below:

```
 Automatic-Module-Name = org.eclipse.e4.core.di
 Build-Jdk-Spec = 11
 Bundle-ActivationPolicy = lazy
 Bundle-Localization = plugin
 Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
 Bundle-Name = Eclipse Dependency Injection
 Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment = JavaSE-11
 Bundle-SymbolicName = org.eclipse.e4.core.di
 Bundle-Vendor = Eclipse.org
 Bundle-Version = 1.8.200.v20220512-1957
 Created-By = Maven Archiver 3.5.2
 Eclipse-SourceReferences = scm:git:https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.runtime.git;path="bundles/org.eclipse.e4.core.di";tag="I20220512-1800";commitId=ada015b6ae742e99f70411886c4f72f1a1fe1713
 Export-Package = org.eclipse.e4.core.di;version="1.7.0",org.eclipse.e4.core.di.suppliers;version="1.7.0",org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di;x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts",org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.osgi;x-internal:=true,org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.shared;x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier"
 Import-Package = javax.inject;version="1.0.0",org.eclipse.osgi.framework.log;version="1.1.0",org.osgi.framework;version="1.8.0",org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.5.1"
 Manifest-Version = 1.0
 Require-Bundle = org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations;bundle-version="[1.4.0,2.0.0)";visibility:=reexport,javax.annotation;bundle-version="[1.3.5,2.0.0)"
```

This Bundle requires the javax.annotation package, but does not import it. We have another Application that is built the same way and that one somehow works. We cannot really figure out why. As I understood OSGi correctly, every plugin has its own classloader and it seems like that javax.annotation is not loaded within the scope of the org.eclipse.e4.core.di plugin. Furthermore in the OSGi runtime it is visible that a javax.annotation bundle is started and active, so it should be available at runtime for the Dependency Injection Plugin.

We wonder how can we add javax.annotation to the OSGi runtime so that it is available for the dependency injection plugin? Has anybody maybe already had a similar problem?

The things we tried so far:

- Adding the javax.annotation dependency to the maven tycho build: This did not change anything at all since the dependency is resolved by OSGi.
- Comparison of the runtime environments of both applications: The OSGi runtimes are the same, we expected to see a difference here.
- We checked all versions of the package and the bundles regarding compatibility, nothing unusual here.
- Adding javax.annotation to the run configuration in eclipse: Did not work as well, nothing changed here.

Eclipse BundleId: 20220609-1112
JDK: 11.0.14.1

Comment: You should have `javax.annotation` in the `Import-Package` in the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Try recompiling it, if it was over the Maven net  link it may been interrupted, or the local maven cache cleared. That should though failed texts and compile somewhere in the output info. Also noticed "application start" in the exception. Runtime annotation processing would-be needed to load before much of anything. Did you use the old binaries untouched or did you recompile?

Comment: `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` has been moved to `jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct`. You have to make sure that all libraries are on the same level.

Comment: @Holger Eclipse includes a javax.annotation plug-in for RCPs with the old javax classes

Comment: @greg-449 so, if library X checks whether library Y is annotated with `jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct`, this check gets somehow converted to a check whether Y is annotated with `javax.annotation.PostConstruct`?

Comment: @Holger This is just for Eclipse/OSGi plug-ins which still use javax.annotation. The question seems to be about such a plug-in.

Comment: @greg-449 yeah that seems to be the problem: org.eclipse.e4.core.di is a plugin provided by eclipse, I dont know in which way I could adjust the Manifest of that. 
To everyone else: I will check your suggestions and give some Feedback, Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: The difficulty may be in the library names now supplied in Maven and it's compile files. Shifting from javax to Jakarta is a source code library compilation problem that mainly affects IBM web IBM eclipse, it splits away from proprietary naming of libraries enforced by Oracle since (aka level) Oracle java 1.8.0_202, the last free licensed Oracle SDK/JRE and equivalent OpenJDK 11. Shortly after, Oracle took over - reserved the javax library name as proprietary. IBM continued source upgrades and used the name Jakarta under the "Jakarta project".  That is immense trouble in JSF tomcat 10.

Comment: Technically Jakarta or javax should not be a problem if the JDK is the only upgrade, however, the jre can trip over older code dependent architectures it's compiled or run on being different.  TIP, anything that uses core SE javax name remains the same, Extended functionalities such as frameworks and libraries e.g. JSF , java servers e.t.c changed since Oracle 1.8.0_202